# Missing event to detect when a specific <v-stepper-content> is shown?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Inside a **vuetify stepper** component I embed my own vue component. I want to define the height of a div depending on its width so that it has the proportions of a "DIN A" sheet.
Problem: The width of the div is 0 when my component is mounted and I don't know when to repeat the measurement.

I need to have the correct proportion of the div and it should be responsive. If I had an event that is fired after the context of my div is shown, I could set the height correctly.

In the **parent** component:

```
<v-stepper-content step="4">
                <ad-preview></ad-preview>
...
```

The template of the **child** component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex class="xs12 sm6" ref="cont">
                <div id="previewPdfContainer">
                </div>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex class="xs12 sm6">
                <h3>Messages</h3>
                <v-btn @click="setContainerSizes">Test</v-btn>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

In the script section I defined these methods:

```
getWindowWidth() {
                this.containerWidth = this.$refs.cont.offsetWidth;
            },
setContainerSizes(){
                this.getWindowWidth();
                this.containerHeight = this.containerWidth * 1.414285714285714;                document.querySelector('#previewPdfContainer').style.width = this.containerWidth + "px";                document.querySelector('#previewPdfContainer').style.height = this.containerHeight + "px";
            }
```

and in mounted() I call "this.setContainerSizes()" - but the width is 0 *because the div is 'invisible' while the component is mounted*!

To **test** the function I included the "Test" button. When I click the button the result is correct: the height of the div is set to the correct value.

I hope there is a planned solution so that I don't have to switch to workarounds with setInterval or via vuex (global value for the 'step' attribute).

I'm grateful for every clue.

Comment: What about asking for this in vuetify's github? https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues

Comment: Watching the step value does not work, because there is a transition on step changing, and the step value changes before the transition is done, which means the new step content is still not displayed (width is 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a workaround, but you can check for the resize of your `v-flex`. Something like the following:

```
new ResizeObserver(setContainerSizes).observe(myVFlex)
```

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, Joao. I have implemented the approach with the ResizeObserver and it works. Since I am still quite new to Vue and Vuetify, I wanted to find out if I just have a knowledge gap before opening an issue on github. Thanks for your answers and comments.